# CodeIgniter file upload validation of ppt and pptx files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, powerpoint

```
$config = array(
            'upload_path' => 'resources/lectures',
            'allowed_types' => 'pdf|zip|doc|docx|ppt|pptx',
            'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
            'overwrite' => FALSE,
            'max_size' => 0,
        );
```

This is my config array for file upload, and all files are uploading fine except for ppt and pptx. I checked the error message using the display_errors() method, it said 'The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is a bug of Codeigniter.**

Open `application/config/mime.php`

and replace `line no 33` (probably) with the following line:

`'ppt'   =>  array('application/powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword'),`

and add the following line to the array:

`'pptx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', 'application/zip', 'application/msword','application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'),`